# How to fix crontab issue with end of file unexpected in script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I wrote a script to check for some services if they are active or not and restart the services.
The script works when ran manually but when added to crontab it does not work, when I check the logs I get

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

This is my script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Checking odoo services"
sudo service odoo13 status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        echo "Odoo not running restarting..."
        sudo service odoo13 restart > /dev/null
fi

echo "Checking nginx services"
sudo service nginx status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        echo "Nginx inactive restarting"
        sudo service nginx restart > /dev/null
fi
```

I set the crontab to run every minute

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/check_services.sh > /dev/null 2>
```

I do not know, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Remove `> /dev/null 2>`.

Comment: Or change `2>` to `2>&1`, just like in your script.

Comment: BTW, if you don't want to print the output of `grep`, use the `-q` option rather than redirecting to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This does not solve the end of file unexpected issue

Comment: Why `2>` at the end?

Comment: @Kenly I have removed it and it still does not work

Comment: Why `*/1`?  Just use `*`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out
instead of #!/bin/bash  I used #!/usr/bin/env bash
strange isn't it?